# Taking sln file from other app

Tags: c#

I worked on some C# app (wpf), I uploaded it as zip file to google drive for now that's the only copy of the project That I have.
The problem is that I forgot to upload the `.sln` file.

When I downloaded the app from google drive to my pc I took some other `.sln` from other app and it worked fine for now.

Is it ok? I mean it can cause any problems in the feature?

Comment: Instead of taking a solution from some other app, you can create a new empty solution (.sln), and add your project to it.

Comment: when you open project without solution, VS just creates it for you, probably it's your case, it doesn't take .sln from other app.

Comment: A solution is basically just a container for projects and build configurations, as you will see if you open it up in a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is sort of like a container that holds all your projects together. So as long as you have a valid project file (`.csproj`) you can simply create your own solution file and add the project to it.

If you go to:

> File > New > Project

you can open up `New Project` dialog box.

There, under:

> Installed > Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions

you can create a blank solution.

[image]

Once you do that, then you can add your existing project to this new empty solution.

For that, go to your Solution Explorer, right click the solution and select `Add > Existing Project` and select your project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I took some other .sln from another app and it worked fine for now:

Most of the time: If you have a single csproj file, all you have to do is double click on the csproj file to build it.  Visual Studio will automatically create a solution for your single csproj.

> Is it ok? I mean it can cause any problems in the feature?

I think the big issues will only come when you have more than one project in your solution.
For example, lets say you have a solution with Project `A` and Project `B`, and project `B` has a reference to `A`.
You will need to add both projects to your new solution so that .NET knows to build `A` first, then build `B` using the output from building `A`.